# FastAPI - Unable to test error responses with custom error handler

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

In FastAPI 0.104.1, I have this custom error handler:

*main.py:*

```
def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()

    @app.exception_handler(Exception)
    async def api_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: Exception):
        if isinstance(exc, APIException):  # APIException instances are raised by me for client errors.
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=exc.status_code,
                content={'message': exc.message}
            )
        return JSONResponse(  # Unhandled errors are returned as a generic 500.
            status_code=HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            content={'message': 'Internal server error.'}
        )

    include_routers(app)  # this is a separate function where I do all the app.include_router(...)s
    return app


api = create_app()
```

My test class, which is being ran with pytest:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import api  # FastAPI instance that I showed.


class TestBrands:

    @property
    def client(self) -> TestClient:
        return TestClient(api, base_url=f'http://localhost:8000/brands')

    def test_create_brand_already_exists_exception(self):
        self.client.post('', json={'name': 'schecter', 'founded_in': 1976})
        response = self.client.post('', json={'name': 'schecter'})  # name is already taken and it will raise a subclass of APIException, which the custom error handler is indeed capturing.
        assert response.status_code == 422  # not possible to assert because exception is raised and I don't have any response.
```

The problem is that when I run this test, since this is an API test and I am doing an http request to the test client, I want to have the response itself and assert its status code and error message. But instead, FastAPI is propagating the exception even when it's beign captured by the error handler.
Take into account that if I do the same test with postman, I can see that the error handler is working and returning my custom status code and message.

Comment: Please, provide the code that we can run and see the error you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

The problem was overriding the base_url attribute when creating the test instance:

```
TestClient(api, base_url=f'http://localhost:8000/brands')
```

I was doing this to avoid using the same url in all the requests, but it seems it behaves different when you create the test client without providing base_url:

```
self.client = TestClient(api)
```

and then in the tests use the path without the root url (I think using localhost was wrong).

```
self.client.get('/path/to/endpoint/without_localhost')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.requests import Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from http import HTTPStatus

def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()

    class APIException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, status_code: int, message: str):
            self.status_code = status_code
            self.message = message

    @app.exception_handler(APIException)  # Use a custom exception type
    async def api_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: APIException):
        return JSONResponse(
            status_code=exc.status_code,
            content={'message': exc.message}
        )

    # Define your routers and routes here
    # include_routers(app)

    return app

api = create_app()
```